# Aws AppSync token expiry date

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, datastore

I am using AWS Amplify datastore. App-sync token in internally used by this service. Currently, App-sync token is expired so I changed expired date from **Appsync / Settings / API keys**. But this allow to edit expired date maximum for next one year.

Is their any why to set token expiry date forever or more then 1 year? because my client don't want that after one year we need to again change expiry date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> [AppSync API key docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authz.html#api-key-authorization): API keys are configurable for up to 365 days, and you can extend an existing expiration date for up to another 365 days from that day.

You can [extend the expiry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateApiKey.html) of an existing key programatically, but if you try to update the expiry (seconds since epoch) beyond one year, you will get the following error: `The API key expiration must be set to a value between 1 and 365 days`.

```sh
aws appsync update-api-key --api-id xxxxxxxx --id da2-xxxxxxxx --expires 1669880629
```

You could automate key updates with a lambda triggered by an [EventBridge cron schedule rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html).

Comment: could you explain me how is the sintax for update the expiration date? I know how to generate the event that trigger the lambda but, inside the lambda how is the sintax

Comment: @WhiteAB The SDKs implement the command in the same way. See the [UpdateApiKeyCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-appsync/classes/updateapikeycommand.html) in the JS SDK, for instance.  Feel free to ask a new question if you need more help.